# disable mic with alsa mixer

Tags: sound, alsa, microphone

previously `alsamixer` used to display volume bars in the terminal which I could navigate using my `->` and `<-` keys, but after I've installed the ubuntu 20.04, it displays something like this:

[image]
I can't say for sure which item is what and which one is my mike. How do I get to display previous sort of display like the volume bars [as shown in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6RFCf.png)   as I want to disable my microphone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alsamixer shows the HDMI sound, so press F6 key and select the second sound card.
Alternatively, launch  alsamixer using:
`alsamixer -c1`